# Tomcat7 in debian:wheezy Docker instance fails to start

Tags: debian, tomcat7, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to build a docker image for the first time using a debian image from Google (google/debian:wheezy), setting up OpenJDK7 on it and trying to setup Tomcat7.

```
docker pull google/debian:wheezy
docker run -i -t google/debian:wheezy bash
```

Once I'm in bash, I install openjdk with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

After a while, I get an error and I must run

```
 apt-get update --fix-missing
 apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
 apt-get install tomcat7
```

After Tomcat7 is installed, I try to start it with

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
[FAIL] Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat7 failed!
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, I'm getting the exact same behaviour on both my Debian Docker installation and my OSX Docker installation (at least it's consistent, that's kinda impressive!)

Looking in /var/log/catalina.out doesn't show any errors, neither does the localhost logs.

I've followed the same process with a normal debian:wheezy image and getting exactly the same failure without any errors.
Any idea where I'm screwing up?

Comment: Try to start it directly instead of using the init.d script and see what happens. I haven't tried the google images, but the official ubuntu ones don't seem to handle the init.d scripts very well.

Comment: @ivant, I created a new image and manually downloaded tomcat__.tar.gz, for both tomcat7 and tomcat8, I just run bin/catalina.sh start and it started up fine. So, it seems the problem is with Debian's init script.
Your comment is the best answer so far, please post as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried your steps and was able to run tomcat just fine. I didn't get the problem with apt-get, so now `apt-get update --fix-missing` was required. I even started tomcat from the init.d script and it worked.

My guess is, that either you had some network problems, or there were some problems with Debian's repositories, but they got fixed.

In any case you should note, that the container is running as long as the specified command is running. That means, that you should either run tomcat in the foreground or ensure the same thing in another way. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241292/dockerized-nginx-is-not-starting/24241634#24241634) for some options.

[EDIT]

I've created a `Dockerfile` to test this. Here it is:

```
FROM google/debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre tomcat7

ADD run.sh /root/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/run.sh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/root/run.sh"]
```

And here is the `run.sh` script that it uses:

```
#!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start

# The container will run as long as the script is running, that's why
# we need something long-lived here
exec tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

Here is a sample build and run session:

```
$ docker build -t tomcat7-test .
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 tomcat7-test
```

Now you should be able to see tomcat's "It works !" page on `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Did a clean pull google/debian:wheezy, I'm not getting the --fix-missing issue anymore, but tomcat is still not starting up (if I manually download it and do catalina.sh start, that works fine). Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Using dockerfiles, it worked flawlessly, it took me a while to figure out that I needed to add a "." (or ./) at the end of the docker build command, thought that dot was just a dust spec on my screen :p

Answer (score 3):

You can use **service tomcat start** in your Dockerfile, just add **--privileged=true** parameter with docker run command. Tomcat needs extended privileges.

Just be sure to understand security implications of this flag.
More information here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to build your image from a [Dockerfile](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/). This is way more explicit, consistent and maintainable, docker will output errors if some arise during the build.

The beginning of the Dockerfile would be, for instance :

```
FROM google/debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Jan Vladimir Mostert <JanVladimirMostert@example.com>
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
RUN apt-get install tomcat7
```

Thus you can start tomcat in the Dockerfile.

Comment: @Pak, good advise, but it doesn't solve the problem by itself. In fact my workflow is to start building the image interactively and add the commands in the Dockerfile when I see they do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu:Trusty following docker run options resolved issue with tomcat start ( start-stop-daemon actualy)

```
docker run -itd --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt=apparmor:unconfined mytomcat7image
```