# Tomcat not running on docker image

Tags: tomcat7, docker, ubuntu-10.04

I installed tomcat7 on the image using Dockerfile through the command :

```
MAINTAINER Abc Xyz <abc@xyz.com>
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jre
RUN apt-get -y install tomcat7 
EXPOSE 8080
```

When I build the image and try to run the following command :

```
sudo docker run -d -P abcxyz/tomcat service tomcat7 start
```

I don't get to see the tomcat page on the port to which it is mapped (say 49153)...
And when I run as a bash in the image and I try :

```
service tomcat7 start
```

Then also it fails to start the tomcat7 server.
I think that the problem is that image is unable to start the tomcat7 server. And I heard that docker images can't run any upstart services though I am not sure.

Anybody has any idea how to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265354/tomcat7-in-debianwheezy-docker-instance-fails-to-start

But still can anybody tell me why it was not happening the way I wanted it?

Comment: Is this the whole Dockerfile? Looks like it's missing `FROM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working, because the container will work for as long as the program you specified is running. The `service tomcat7 start` command finishes immediately.

Comment: so in the file given on the link...what does the last line do??
Does is make it run constantly??

Comment: Exactly. `tail -f` will monitor the file for changes and will print them as they become available. There are many other option as well. Like `while true; do sleep 1d; done`.

Answer (score 6):

change the command to

```
<path/to/tomcat>/bin/cataline.sh run
```

and this will make tomcat run in the forground

Comment: I'll try it and get back :)

Comment: The command in the Docker file should be like **ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh", "run" ]**

Comment: Just tested it on Ubuntu 14.04. You need "export CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7" before "/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run". It deployed and served a simple webapp okay.

Answer (score 6):

Just add:

```
--privileged=true
```

parameter with docker run command. Tomcat need extended privileges to run.

More informations there: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You should run it like so:

```
docker run -dP abcxyz/tomcat catalina.sh run
```

This will make the container run as long as the command is executing. The way you were running it though is having the service as a background process.

Answer (score 0):

use docker run with -d switch to run in detach mode. So it will run in background.
eg: 
docker run -d abcd /path/catalina.sh run