# Dockerfile to install Nginx and MySQL in same image

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, dockerfile, linux-containers

I want to install nginx and mysql in same image. I start out with a mysql image with the plan to install docker using dockerfile.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=HelloWorld \
    MYSQL_DATABASE=content
RUN apt update
RUN apt install nginx -y
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This starts the mysql db perfectly and nginx also gets installed. Unfortunately, nginx doesn't start. To start nginx I also added another command in the docker file:

```
CMD service nginx start
```

After adding this line in the dockerfile, the container closes after creation. What am I doing wrong here?
I am using below command to start container with above image:

```
docker run -it -p 3306:3306 -p 8080:80 -p 8081:443 --name mycontainer myimage
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241292/dockerized-nginx-is-not-starting .

Comment: You'd almost always want to run these two very different components in separate containers.  (If you change your proxy configuration, why do you need to also restart your database at the same time?  If you need an HA database configuration, why do you need to scale the proxy exactly the same amount?)  Further, commands like `service` don't really work in Docker; separate containers let you run the two separate processes as foreground processes, and you can probably use standard Docker Hub images for both.

Answer (score 1):

it's best to run each process in a separate container. but if you wanna do that, you should create a bash file to start MySQL and Nginx. finally, you should use that bash file as the `ENTRYPOINT` of your image/container